# Finding non-linear correlations in R

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I have about 90 variables stored in data[2-90]. I suspect about 4 of them will have a parabola-like correlation with data[1]. I want to identify which ones have the correlation. Is there an easy and quick way to do this?

I have tried building a model like this (which I could do in a loop for each variable i = 2:90):

```
y <- data$AvgRating
x <- data$Hamming.distance
x2 <- x^2

quadratic.model = lm(y ~ x + x2)
```

And then look at the R^2/coefficient to get an idea of the correlation. Is there a better way of doing this?

Maybe R could build a regression model with the 90 variables and chose the ones which are significant itself? Would that be in any way possible? I can do this in JMP for linear regression, but I'm not sure I could do non-linear regression with R for all the variables at ones. Therefore I was manually trying to see if I could see which ones are correlated in advance. It would be helpful if there was a function to use for that.

Comment: What is the structure of `data`? Is it a list of vectors? are all the vectors the same length?

Comment: They are all the same length. I read them in with 
data = read.csv("file", header = TRUE). I think it had to do with the headers, I changed the question to reflect the working code.

Comment: If `data` is a `data.frame` then `data[1]` gives you a one column `data.frame` while `lm` expects a vector. Use `data[[1]]` to get the vector.

Comment: Please define what you understand as "correlation". The Spearman correlation coefficient tests for monotonic relationships.

Comment: Indeed, if you can just combine all of the variables into a single matrix, then you can get all of the pairwise spearman correlations using `cor(dat, method='spearman')`.

Comment: The problem is that they will have a non-monotonic relationship (so parabola like). I was wondering if I could capture that type of correlation in some way. The goal in the end is to find about 4 variables which are significant to build a non-linear lm model.

Comment: "The goal in the end is to find about 4 variables which are significant to build a non-linear lm model." Then you are not approaching this in a good way.

Comment: @Roland. I was wondering if there is a function to see an overview of the highly correlated (non-linear) variables, in order to be more informed when building an lm. If there is a better way to approach this I would love to know...

Comment: Thanks snaut, that really helps to make a loop :)

Comment: Is there a way to do stepwise regression with non-linear formulas perhaps?

Comment: I don't know why you want to model this, but if the relationships are not linear a Generalized Additive Model is probably preferable. The implementation in package mgcv can remove variables.

Comment: If you want to build ``lm`` with quadratic term in x, you can use ``lm(y ~ x + I(x)^2``

Comment: Thanks Phann, but that would only be for 1 variable X, or all 90? Basically when I build it for 90 I will loose degrees of freedom, so I want to see in advance which ones would be potentially correlated

Comment: Maybe applying it on every column would help? ``lapply(df, function(x) lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))``. Mention that it is ``I(x^2)`` not as my comment before. With ``sapply(df, function(x) lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))[[1]][3])`` or similar you could get the important parameters of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to compute mutual information score between each pair of variables. For example, using the `mutinformation` function from the [infotheo package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/infotheo/), you could do:

```
set.seed(1)

library(infotheo)

# corrleated vars (x & y correlated, z noise)
x <- seq(-10,10, by=0.5)
y <- x^2
z <- rnorm(length(x))

# list of vectors
raw_dat <- list(x, y, z)


# convert to a dataframe and discretize for mutual information
dat <- matrix(unlist(raw_dat), ncol=length(raw_dat))
dat <- discretize(dat)

mutinformation(dat)
```

**Result**:

```
|   |        V1|        V2|        V3|                                                                                            
|:--|---------:|---------:|---------:|                                                                                            
|V1 | 1.0980124| 0.4809822| 0.0553146|                                                                                            
|V2 | 0.4809822| 1.0943907| 0.0413265|                                                                                            
|V3 | 0.0553146| 0.0413265| 1.0980124|
```

By default, `mutinformation()` computes the discrete empirical mutual information score between two or more variables. The `discretize()` function is necessary if you are working with continuous data transform the data to discrete values.

This might be helpful at least as a first stab for looking for nonlinear relationships between variables, such as that described above.

Comment: Can I use this to arbitrary data set, i.e. not necessarily stationary? thanks

Comment: Hi @pythonnovice, I haven't worked with that type of data before, so I can't really say for sure. Probably the easiest thing to do would be to simulate some simple non-stationary data and try it out.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `nlcor` package in R. This package finds the nonlinear correlation between two data vectors.
There are different approaches to estimate a nonlinear correlation, such as infotheo. However, nonlinear correlations between two variables can take any shape.

`nlcor` is robust to most nonlinear shapes. It works pretty well in different scenarios.

At a high level, `nlcor` works by adaptively segmenting the data into linearly correlated segments. The segment correlations are aggregated to yield the nonlinear correlation. The output is a number between 0 to 1. With close to 1 meaning high correlation. Unlike a pearson correlation, negative values are not returned because it has no meaning in nonlinear relationships.

More details about this package [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/estimating-non-linear-correlation-in-r-62c6571cb1db)

To install `nlcor`, follow these steps:

```
install.packages("devtools") 
library(devtools)
install_github("ProcessMiner/nlcor")
library(nlcor)
```

After you install it,

```
# Implementation 
x <- seq(0,3*pi,length.out=100)
y <- sin(x)
plot(x,y,type="l")
```

[image: sin(x) plot]

```
# linear correlation is small
cor(x,y)
# [1] 6.488616e-17
# nonlinear correlation is more representative
nlcor(x,y, plt = T)
# $cor.estimate
# [1] 0.9774
# $adjusted.p.value
# [1] 1.586302e-09
# $cor.plot
```

[image: using nlcor for sin(x)]

As shown in the example the linear correlation was close to zero although there was a clear relationship between the variables that `nlcor` could detect.

Note: The order of x and y inside the `nlcor` is important. `nlcor(x,y)` is different from `nlcor(y,x)`. The x and y here represent 'independent' and 'dependent' variables, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Fitting a generalized additive model, will help you identify curvature in the
relationships between the explanatory variables. Read the example on page 22 [here](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CEEQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww3.imperial.ac.uk%2Fpls%2Fportallive%2Fdocs%2F1%2F1171924.PDF&rct=j&q=fit%20a%20tree%20model%20to%20see%20whether%20complex%20interactions%20between%20the%20explanatory%20variables%20are%20indicated&ei=kmfuTK7tK9eAhAfa7tzvCw&usg=AFQjCNGLtFOjUeikDVtZiDUBhOV5X1Zklg&sig2=L_z9Y9tydlZx55kUtXrfPQ&cad=rja).

Comment: Thank you. I tried this using the gam function. With too many variables I get an error about too few degrees of freedom though. So I'm thinking I should do this per variable first to see which ones are most suited. Or am I missing a function that gam can identify the variables?